# Inheriting templated constructor from class template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, constructor

What would be the syntax to inherit constructors (some of them are template) from a class template in C++11 ?

```
template <class T>
struct Base
{
    using type = T;
    explicit constexpr Base(const type& x): value{x} {};
    template <class U> explicit constexpr Base(U&& x): value{std::forward<U>(x)} {};
    type value;
}

struct Derived: Base<bool>
{
    using Base::Base<bool>; // Does not seem to work ?!?
}
```

Comment: Try `using Base<bool>::Base;`  (I didn't try it myself, but I'm sure you need the `<bool>` before the `::` and only unsure about what works after the `::`)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  If you want the Base<bool> bool constructor then you don't want the templated constructor.  Then you simply say `using Base<bool>::Base` as JSF suggests.

Comment: Constructors must be all inherited together, you can't pick and choose. (However, default, copy, and move constructors are automatically excluded.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You derive from `Base<bool>`. So your base class is `Base<bool>`, and inheriting the constructors is done via

```
using Base<bool>::Base;
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3245183b8e94d978)

You do not need `Base<bool>` after the `::`, in fact the code doesn't compile if you put it. The constructors are still referred to as `Base`, and not `Base<bool>`. This is consistent with referring to member functions of class templates: you use e.g. `void Foo<int>::f()` and not `void Foo<int>::f<int>()` to refer to the `Foo`'s member function `f()`.